# python - why is it possible to use a variable in a function that is declared in the main scope and is not global

Tags: python, global-variables

I recently noticed something that I was not expected with python, it is possible to check/access a variable inside a function that is declared in the main scope, e.g.:

```
def my_func(mval):
    print ("parameter:", mval)
    print ("myvar:", myvar)
    #myvar = "value" this is not allowed

print ("IN MAIN")
myvar = "123"
my_func(999)
```

Output:

```
IN MAIN
parameter: 999
myvar: 123
```

1. Why `my_func` can access the `myvar`? And then why it fails when
   trying to change the value?
2. Is there a way to prevent this behavior,
   so in this case it would say variable `myvar` is not defined?

I know we could use `global` to make this work and it would make sense since we are explicitly saying there is a variable outside of the function scope that we want to access.

I find this tricky because it could lead to errors..

Answer (score 1):

`myvar` is in the global scope so its global whether you declare it or not. When read, python looks in the function's local scope and then falls back to the module global scope where the variable is defined. When written, python has a problem. Should it assign the variable in the local function scope or the global scope? The `global` keyword is used in the function and tells that function how to resolve that problem. The variable is never declared global, the function is told to treat that variable as global.

```
def my_func(mval):
    global myval
    myval = 'foo'  # set in global scope
    myval2 = 'bar' # set in local scope
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I know that the `global` keyword would solve the issue. Just find it weird the behavior without the global keyword. It might leads to errors if one types by mistake a variable that should not be used/valid in the current scope. Is there a way to avoid it? So it would return an error?

Comment: Python checks multiple scopes when reading variables as a convenience. As long as you write a local variable before you read it, there is no confusion. By the time you read it, its been created in the local scope. The risk is when you mistakenly read a variable that you think should be in the local scope but is really in the global scope. In that case you want an error but you get bad data. Dynamic languages stand up and bite us in the rear from time to time!

Answer (score 1):

When you display the content of `myvar` in `my_func` with the exact code you gave as reference, it will check the global variable table to see if it was previously defined in the execution, which is why it works. Then, when you try to assign a value to it in the function by uncommenting `myvar = "value"`, it tries to define `myvar` as a local variable of `my_func`, which shadows the reference to the global instance of `myvar`.

I'm not exactly sure how using the `global` keyword would cause any issue, but it should be working as intended. Here is an example of how you can use it:

```
def my_func(mval):
    global myvar
    print ("parameter:", mval)
    print ("myvar:", myvar)
    myvar = "value"

print ("IN MAIN")
myvar = "123"
my_func(999)
print("myvar after my_func:", myvar)
```

Output:

```
IN MAIN
parameter: 999
myvar: 123
myvar after my_func: value
```

If you really don't want to use the `global` keyword, you can achieve the desired behavior by passing `myvar` as a parameter of `my_func` and return the modified value to reassign it in the main scope:

```
def my_func(mval, myvar):
    print ("parameter:", mval)
    print ("myvar:", myvar)
    myvar = "value"
    return myvar

print ("IN MAIN")
myvar = "123"
myvar = my_func(999, myvar)
print ("myvar after my_func:", myvar)
```

Output:

```
IN MAIN
parameter: 999
myvar: 123
myvar after my_func: value
```

If `my_func` was already built to return a value, remember that you can return multiple values in Python. Therefore, assuming `my_func` would return a variable called `returnvar`, the above code could be written as:

```
def my_func(mval, myvar):
    returnvar = mval + 1
    print ("parameter:", mval)
    print ("myvar:", myvar)
    myvar = "value"
    return myvar, returnvar

print ("IN MAIN")
myvar = "123"
myvar, returnvar = my_func(999, myvar)
print ("myvar after my_func:", myvar)
print ("returnvar:", returnvar)
```

Output:

```
IN MAIN
parameter: 999
myvar: 123
myvar after my_func: value
returnvar: 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define your function it is **not** evaluated for correctness only for syntax, so nothing is raised. Once you call the function `myvar` is already defined in the global scope so the function is valid. Also if you uncomment `myvar = 'value'` `my_func` will also evaluate without exception as long as `myvar` is define before the function is called.